# Convert date to elapsed time

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Right now I have a date value like so:

`2011-04-29T07:08:22.000Z`

I want to turn this in to a live updating (no page refresh) elapsed time representation.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jquery timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/), it's really good and easy.

You just do something like this for initialization :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});
```

And like this everywhere you want some time to be displayed :

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
```

Comment: The only problem I had with it is when your server's time is not really on sync, If your server is like 4 minutes late or something, you will have a 4 minutes error (it only matters if you are displaying content created "now" and it displays "4 minutes ago".. anyway I have a fix for this if you need it ...

Comment: Thanks very much, I ended up implementing it like this -  `data.time = $.timeago(data.time);` Works great, thanks again.